# Function to get results for all values in cursor column in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got problem with query. As for now I've got:

```
create or replace function f_test(par_cat in varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
  l_str varchar2(1000);
  l_rc  sys_refcursor;
begin
  for cur_r in (select cat, kw_crt
                  from (select owner_category cat,
                               substr(PROPERTY_ID, 1, 4) kw_crt,
                               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY owner_category 
                               ORDER BY owner_category, substr(PROPERTY_ID, 1, 4)) rank
                          from owners)
                 where rank < 3
                   and cat = par_cat) loop
    l_str := 'select * ' || 'from owners ' ||
             'where substr(PROPERTY_ID,1,4) in (' || chr(39) ||
             cur_r.kw_crt || chr(39) || ')' || '  and Owner_category    = ' ||
             chr(39) || cur_r.cat || chr(39);
  end loop;

  open l_rc for l_str;
  return l_rc;
end;
/
```

where

```
select owner_category cat,
       substr(PROPERTY_ID, 1, 4) kw_crt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY owner_category ORDER BY owner_category, 
       substr(PROPERTY_ID, 1, 4)) rank
  from owners)
 where rank < 3
   and cat = par_cat
```

is table

```
+---------+----------+
|  cat    |  kw_crt  |
+---------+----------+
| retired | AAD1     |
| retired | AAH2     |
+---------+----------+
```

The problem is when I run this function I receive results with only 'AAH2' code and I would like to get for all values in col kw_crt meaning AAH2 or AAD1. Could you help me change the function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat SQL query redundantly, and looping is not needed also. Just need to use bind variable for `par_cat` parameter (call `:i_par_cat`) within the query string to bring all records conforming to your query in the result set. So, recreate your function as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(par_cat in varchar2) RETURN sys_refcursor is
  l_str varchar2(1000);
  l_rc  sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    l_str := 'SELECT cat, kw_crt
                FROM (SELECT owner_category cat,
                             SUBSTR(property_id, 1, 4) kw_crt,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY owner_category 
                             ORDER BY owner_category, SUBSTR(property_id, 1, 4)) rank
                        FROM owners)
                 WHERE rank < 3
                   AND cat = :i_par_cat';

  OPEN l_rc FOR l_str USING par_cat;
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way to much work looping through a cursor to build a dynamic query. Actually you do not need dynamic SQL (Execute Immediate) at all.  Dynamic SQL is required only when you do not know the name of a db object (Table, Column, etc). In this case all that is known; the only unknown is the **value** of the parameter. So

```
create or replace 
function f_test(p_par_cat in varchar2) 
  return sys_refcursor 
is
  l_rc  sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_rc for 
       select cat, kw_crt
         from ( select owner_category cat 
                     , substr(property_id, 1, 4) kw_crt 
                     , row_number()
                            over (partition by owner_category 
                                      order by owner_category, substr(property_id, 1, 4)
                                 ) rank
                 from owners
              )
        where rank < 3
          and cat = p_par_cat;
  return l_rc;
end f_test;

-- test
declare 
   rcursor sys_refcursor;
   cat     owners.owner_category%type;
   kw_crt  owners.property_id%type;
begin
   rcursor := f_test('retired');
   dbms_output.put_line('cat' || chr(09)|| chr(09) || 'kw_crt'); 
   loop
      fetch rcursor 
       into cat, kw_crt;
      exit when rcursor%notfound;
     -- dbms_output.put_line('cat: ' || cat || '  kw_crt: ' || kw_crt);
     dbms_output.put_line(cat || chr(09) || kw_crt);     
   end loop;
end;
```

You also claim you only get 1 of the expected rows in the output. Helping with that requires you to post post the calling routine, which but you failed to do. Post that if you still need further help.